# Powershell module does not load after installing patch

Tags: powershell, autoload, powershell-4.0, import-module, powershell-module

I am facing an issue related to auto-loading of modules after a patch installation. Sequence is as follows:

- I have a .NET service running in version say 1.0.8802
- From Powershell (V 4.0) I see that the module `MyAgent` is loaded and it's commandlets are accessible
- Even after I restart the computer, the `MyAgent` is loaded when I open Powershell (without having to explicitly execute any load/get-module command)
- Now I install a patch for my .NET service using WUA (Windows Update Agent). The patch installs successfully and automatically restarts the computer
- Now I open PowerShell, the `MyAgent` is NOT loaded. It appears in `Get-Module -ListAvailable`. Once I run `Import-Module MyAgent` then everything starts working as before.

**Points to note:**

- MyAgent module is present in `c:\windows\system32\Windowspowershell\v1.0\modules` in both cases
- In both cases the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` is null
- My `$env:PSModulePath` is also correct pointing to `c:\windows\system32\Windowspowershell\v1.0\modules\`

The reason I'm perplexed is, why is the module not loading automatically after the patch installs (despite the module being present in the correct modules folder)? This issue resolves when I create a profile file in `C:\Users\<<user>>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` with content as `Import-Module MyAgent`. Ironically, If I keep the profile file in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1` the patch installation itself fails without any clear error. What am I missing here?

Kindly help!

Comment: What do you mean by not loaded? Modules gets auto-imported after you've used it. Ex. "CimCmdlets" module is not loaded before I run `Get-CimInstance` or another cmdlet in the module. Are you saying that tabcompletion for the cmdlets in `MyAgent` doesn't work before you manually imported it?

Comment: Frode, I meant that tab completion doesnt work and also, if i try to use any commandlet defined in that module it says "is not recognised as a commandlet" error message. If I explicitly run "Import-Module" then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been open for a few weeks... if you haven't solved the issue yet you should try putting your module in `c:\Program Files\WindowsPowershell\Modules`.

I haven't experienced an issue putting modules in `c:\windows\system32\Windowspowershell\v1.0\modules`, but from what I understand, there can be issues related to updates.  As of PS3 (I believe) Custom modules should be loaded in `c:\program files\WindowsPowershell\Modules`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue that the modules were not loading automatically for a specific user. For others it was fine...

All my modules are located in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` but auto-completion with intellisense or loading them automatically when needed was not working anymore.

**Some facts:**

```
$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference 
# empty
$env:PSModulePath 
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules # and others
Get-Module -ListAvailable
# Shows my custom made modules
```

**Solution:**

Deleted the profile of the user in question on the server and have the system create a new one.